# Unable to format a float elapsed time when reading in serial data from Arduino

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to export, as a csv, the incoming data from sensors connected to an Arduino using the following python 3 program:

```
import serial
import time
import csv

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411')
ser.flushInput()
print("Press Ctrl+C to stop data logging")
file=open("datalogger.csv","w")

start_time=time.time()

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes=ser_bytes.decode("ascii").split(',')
        print(decoded_bytes)
        t=time.time()-start_time
        print(t)
        t2="{:.2f}".format(t)
        writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow([t2,decoded_bytes[0], decoded_bytes[1]])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program stopped")
        file.close()
        break
```

However no matter what I try, the saved csv **continues to show the elapsed time (variable t) unrounded**. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Have you been logging to this file a while and happened to write `t` to it instead of `t2`... have you checked the last rows of the file to check if they're formatted correctly - as your code should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Yes I've just discovered that replugging in the USB cable each time seems to reset the serial communication, and then it works fine. Any idea why this is required?

Comment: Not that I can think of at nearly midnight :)